# Kivy regarding Popup Windows and Screens

Tags: kivy, screen, popupwindow

i have a question, in Kivy is it possible to change to another screen from popup window?

Comment: The answer is: "Yes!"

Comment: May i know how to do it? I wrote a code once user input a correct date correctly and press okay, the popup window will close and goes to a screen. But it seems like my code is not working. i use self.parent.current = 'boost_screen' (< this code is not working)

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducable example of your code. Minimum as in minimum lines of code which shows your problem, but not to much of the rest of the app. It is a lot easier to help if you have some code which I can copy and paste and then look for a solution. Also it shows you are putting in some effort not just the person replying. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution

[image]

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

kv = """
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<ChangePopup>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (200, 200)

    Button: 
        text: "Change screen"
        on_press: app.root.current = 'screen2'; root.dismiss()

ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Screen1"
            Button:
                text: "Open Popup to change to Screen2"
                on_press: Factory.ChangePopup().open()
    Screen:
        name: 'screen2'
        Label:
            text: "Screen2"
"""

class ChangePopup(Popup):
    pass

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can i ask what is the difference of using Factory to open the popup and using Popup().open() in python file

Comment: To be frank. I am not really sure. It does not work without Factory. I think you might need Factory, because python might not already know about this class at this point. But I am really guessing here. I would suggest posting it as another question if you really want to know.
Please accept my answer if it solves your question. It is a small appreciation for the time I put in to solve this question. Thanks.